# .NET analyzers code analysis: how to see results

Tags: .net

I clicked this
[image]

Is something supposed to happen?

I was expecting it to tell me about

```
    public class naughty_class
    {
        public string[] Foo { get; set; }
    }
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: I would expect Warnings or Information messages popping up in the Error List tool window.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I imagined would happen. But nothing.